# How to prove $\vdash (\forall v_1 \,\exists v_2\, fv_1=v_2)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

f is a one-place function symbol.

I just don't know where to start.

$\forall v_1 \,\exists v_2\, fv_1=v_2$ might come from  $\exists v_2 \,fv_1=v_2$

Then I don't know how to deal with the "exists"

Comment: Can you use the completeness theorem?

Comment: I haven't learned it yet. I only learned to use axioms and rules of inference to deduct it.

Comment: What rules do you have regarding functions?

Comment: This is the first exercise asks me to deal with functions. So I just regarded it as a term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basic idea (we are working in FOL, first-order logic, where it is assumed that any function sign expresses a total function, i.e. function which produces a value for any input). By the identity rules you have

$$fa = fa.$$

That's because you have $\tau = \tau$ for any [closed] term $\tau$, and $fa$ is of course a term. Whence, by existential quantifier introduction (you can instantiate on any term),

$$\exists v_2\,fa = v_2$$

But $a$ was arbitrary, so you can use universal quantifier introduction to derive

$$\forall v_1\exists v_2\,fv_1= v_2.$$

How exactly you implement this idea inside your preferred deductive system will depend on its fine details.

Comment: I got the idea. Can the existential quantifier introduction be proved by other rules? I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: It depends what other rules you know!

Comment: @user144470 - as per PSmith's comment, in order to give you the "correct" proof, it is necessary to know the rules you are allowed to use. Being a problem of f-o logic, I assume that you know the axiom : $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha[x := t]$, where $t$ is a *term* used to substitute in in place of $x$ into $\alpha$. Form this axioms, using $\lnot \alpha$, we get : $\forall x \lnot \alpha \rightarrow \lnot \alpha[x := t]$. By *contraposition* and *double negation* we get : $\alpha[x := t] \rightarrow \lnot \forall x \lnot \alpha$. 1/2

Comment: Finally, we use the definition (or equivalence) of $\exists$ as $\lnot \forall \lnot$ to conclude : $\alpha [x:=t] \rightarrow \exists x \alpha$. Of course, the applicability of all of the above steps must be checked with the axioms and rules of your textbook. The logical theorem $\alpha [x:=t] \rightarrow \exists x \alpha$ has been used by PS in his proof as a "derived rule" : $\alpha [x:=t] \vdash \exists x \alpha$, with $fa=fa$ as $\alpha$.

Comment: For a different proof of it, see Herbert Enderton, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd - 2001), page 116. For the corresponding proof in *natural deduction*, see Dirk van Dalen, *Logic and Structure* (5th ed - 2013), page 91.

Comment: Peter help ... I'm in trouble. If I understand e.g.Enderton well, the subst into $∀xα→α[x:=t]$ is "total" (see page 112 : "Here $α[x:=t]$ is the expression obtained from the formula $\alpha$ by replacing the variable $x$, *wherever it occurs free in* $\alpha$ [emphasis added], by the term $t$"). Thus, how we may justify the "partial" subst into $fa=fa$ to get $∃v_2(fa=v_2)$ instead of $∃v_2(v_2=v_2)$ ?

Comment: Mauro, Enderton would get from $\varphi(fa)$ to $\exists v_2\varphi(v_2)$ as on p. 116. That works for any $\varphi$ [leaving aside worries about other occurrences of $v_2$], including ones with other occurrences of $a$. Put $\varphi(\cdot)$ to be $(fa = \cdot)$.

Comment: @PeterSmith - you are right ! Thanks a lot.